# Prevent calling a TypeScript class as a function - _classCallCheck

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm writing a library in TypeScript that will be consumed by all flavours of JS. When I write a class and try and calling it in TS without `new`, it rightly won't compile.

In ES6/Babel, when I create a class, it automatically adds the `_classCallCheck` function to check that it's been called with `new` at runtime.

Is there a similar flag in TypeScript to add such a check? Obviously it won't be used when I use the library in TypeScript, but will when it's written in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a similar flag in TypeScript to add such a check?

No. You have to write it manually.

I've added a feature request : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6569

Comment: I've added some more detail to the GitHub request. I shall look to create a pull request on this with a fixture soon. Thanks.